# Length of symbols in the alphabet of the Oxford English Dictionary.

Tags: logic, automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

Consider an alphabet $A$ comprised of singleton symbols, so for example we might have $A=\{a,b,c,...,z\}$ or even $A=\{0,1\}$ among many others. The length of each symbol in these alphabets is one.

If I took as my alphabet the set of all words appearing in the *Oxford English Dictionary*, would each word (word here in the sense of symbol in my alphabet) have length one?

Comment: It seems to me that the question posed in the second paragraph is answered in the first paragraph: "the length of each symbol in these alphabets is one".

Comment: If your alphabet includes {..., *diction, dictional, dictionally, dictionaries, dictionary, dictions,* ...} and you define the length of each to be one, then each is of length one. Clearly each is *one word* in standard English, so you may need to be careful if you want to use the word *word* to mean something else.